# What does "restore purchases" in In-App purchases mean?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, restore

I don't really understand this idea.
Do I have to provide a restore button for the user?
What method should this method invoke?
What will restore will do?

Comment: Basically, if you delete the app, move to a new phone, whatever, your purchases will no longer be available on that device. Restore Purchases asks iTunes what of the available in-app purchases you've paid for. You should provide a restore button, I'm not sure if it's required but it's definitely suggested. You should read the docs on in app purchases to get a clearer idea what part of the purchase/restore transaction are your responsibility, and which part is Apple's.

Comment: I am no iPhone expert, but from experience of using one, if you have in-app purchases, this method should restore everything that user has purchased from/in your app, of course you will use they are apple ID/account for identification.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You typically restore purchases with this code:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

It will reinvoke `-paymentQueue:updatedTransactions` on the observer(s) for the purchased items. This is useful for users who reinstall the app after deletion or install it on a different device.

Not all types of In-App purchases can be restored.

Comment: Isn't there something similar to App rebuy? Isn't it prompts that similar "You have purchased, so you can download for free"? I had no such experience.

Comment: No this has to be implemented by the app developer in order to provide this experience to the user - but its rather simple (one line of code).

Comment: I can't catch any delegated methods when a user have no any purchases made, and hit restore. Store gets processing, but no methods get invoked in such case (only paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:, but it gets invoked at successful restores too). So what now? I'll setup a question for this.

Comment: what if my own server manages by checking paid restriction at runtime.
so if person deletes & install an app still he/she will get all paid feature.(at that time do I really need this?)

Answer (score 8):

You will get rejection message from apple just because the product you have registered for inApp purchase might come under category Non-renewing subscriptions and consumable products. These type of products will not automatically renewable. you need to have explicit restore button in your application.

for other type of products it will automatically restore it.

Please read following text which will clear your concept about this :

> Once a transaction has been processed and removed from the queue, your
>   application normally never sees it again. However, if your application
>   supports product types that must be restorable, you must include an
>   interface that allows users to restore these purchases. This interface
>   allows a user to add the product to other devices or, if the original
>   device was wiped, to restore the transaction on the original device.
>
> Store Kit provides built-in functionality to restore transactions for
>   non-consumable products, auto-renewable subscriptions and free
>   subscriptions. To restore transactions, your application calls the
>   payment queue’s restoreCompletedTransactions method. The payment queue
>   sends a request to the App Store to restore the transactions. In
>   return, the App Store generates a new restore transaction for each
>   transaction that was previously completed. The restore transaction
>   object’s originalTransaction property holds a copy of the original
>   transaction. Your application processes a restore transaction by
>   retrieving the original transaction and using it to unlock the
>   purchased content. After Store Kit restores all the previous
>   transactions, it notifies the payment queue observers by calling their
>   paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished: method.
>
> If the user attempts to purchase a restorable product (instead of
>   using the restore interface you implemented), the application receives
>   a regular transaction for that item, not a restore transaction.
>   However, the user is not charged again for that product. Your
>   application should treat these transactions identically to those of
>   the original transaction. Non-renewing subscriptions and consumable
>   products are not automatically restored by Store Kit. Non-renewing
>   subscriptions must be restorable, however. To restore these products,
>   you must record transactions on your own server when they are
>   purchased and provide your own mechanism to restore those transactions
>   to the user’s devices

Comment: Do you know what is happening with scenario when restore is not needed as in following case:
User is able to download application on his device and that app can use multiple users by logging in with different credentials. If user Bill logs in with his credentials and buy app that is bought only for his credentials. If latter Joe logs in with his credentials he should buy it again. If Bill logs on any other device he should be able to enjoy full app. App features depends on data that server returns and not from other assets.

Thanks!

Comment: @ zvjerka24 - yes exectly the same I want in my app, then what IAP i have to use?

Answer (score 2):

Is it as optional functionality.

If you won't provide it when user will try to purchase non-consumable product AppStore will restore old transaction. But your app will think that this is new transaction.

If you will provide restore mechanism then your purchase manager will see restored transaction.

If app should distinguish this options then you should provide functionality for restoring previously purchased products.

Comment: isn't this what app-store should handle ?

Comment: AppStore handle this as it is said in my post. There are only different types of transactions that app will see.

Comment: Isn't there something similar to App rebuy? Isn't it prompts that similar "You have purchased, so you can download for free"? I had no such experience.

Comment: Yes, it prompts such message if product is `non-consumable` and was already bought by that account.

Comment: It's not optional. Apple require you to do this. My app was rejected because I didn't let the user restore their IAPs.

Comment: @Devfly 1 year has passed ;) My app wasn't rejected.

Comment: @Devfly hello Devfly , When a user who not register , how do I restore non-renewing subscriptions for his other devices ? thankyou

Comment: My app was just rejected because it didn't have a restore button for ALL (bear in mind - free price tier) non-consumables. I had individual buttons to re-download if the receipt allowed it, but you had to use in-game currency to 'rebuy' those levels. They equated the in game currency as something the user had 'paid for', thus a restore option was necessary. So maybe it's possible to get passed review if you have a simpler setup.